# google ajax search with jQuery - $.getJSON(). there is any response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-ajax-search-api

i'm trying to make my image search with google ajax search
i'm using jQuery.
so below my code

```
$.getJSON('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=hello', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

the console printed NULL
and my xhr information is

```
request URL:http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=hello
Request Headers
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Origin:http://example.local
Referer:http://example.local/thread/create
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.127 Safari/533.4
```

i'm not sure what's wong.
help me plz

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your URL needs a slight tweak to trigger JSONP, add `&callback=?` on the end, like this:

```
$.getJSON('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=hello&callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

[You can see it working here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/vNN6D/), take a look at the console.

If jQuery sees a `callback=?` in the url, it replaces it with a function name it generates (which is your `function(data)` callback), and that's what gets run when the JSONP request comes back.  See [the `$.getJSON()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) for the same info.

Without this it's trying to do an XmlHttpRequest, and being blocked by [the same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), since it's on another domain.

Comment: Nick's got it right... the callback parameter is wrapping the json in a javascript function.  Jquery replaces the ? with something random and run-time generates the random name callback function.